# Calling android native java code from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webserver

I would like to develop an application to transfer files between the android device and PC over wifi.

I have a webserver and a service set up and when a button is clicked the web server service is called and it serves a html page from the assets folder over http. This page could be accessed over wifi by typing the ip address of the phone:port number.

But to do something useful with the application,I have been looking for a way to call native android code from the javascript functions in the html page.

Most of the examples I have looked for involve calling android code from webview. I was wondering if there was a way to call it from javascript without web view/dummy web view.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want the JavaScript (running in your *computers* browser) to call Java methods on your *Android* device?

Comment: nope.avi Just cant see how this would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a way to call it from javascript without web view/dummy web view.

No, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Comment: Any alternate ways to achieve this using other technologies?

Comment: @kalz: Your Web server can generate Web pages on the fly, as Web servers have done for nearly two decades. Those pages would be generated by the Java code on your server. That being said, I hope that you are a security expert and/or have a large legal defense fund, as if you screw this up and allow arbitrary people (other than the device owner) to access private data from the device without the user's consent, expect to be sued.

Comment: @CommsWare.I am protecting it with a random password generated every time the server is started.Only on successful verification of password can one use the app.

Comment: @kalz: That's a good starting point. Since presumably this is some sort of single-user thing, you might also want to add fairly aggressive defenses against brute-force attacks (e.g., automatically shut down the server after three failures, forcing the user to start the server again from the on-device UI).

Comment: @CommonsWare-I will consider your suggestions .So looks like it has to be on the fly then.Thanks for your inputs everyone.